# 400 Bad Request in android

Tags: android, xml, web-services, rest-client

I am posting an API on Restclient by GET method. Till Yesterday My response Status code was 200 Ok. But Today I am Getting 400 Bad Request as my response Status Code.

Following is response body

> System.Exception: Failed to deserialize response.
>
> Response: System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (1, 2). ---> System.InvalidOperationException:  was not expected.

I am not sure if I am doing something wrong in my source code or something went wrong on web service side.

If anyone could help.

Comment: *Till Yesterday My response Status code was 200 Ok*. If you did not change anything then we can presume the fault is server side

Comment: what @blackbelt said + without further details it will be impossible to offer any more specific answer (example of request and response might help)

Comment: _**There is an error in XML document**_ is pushing me to think the error is on server side. Not sure